# onclientclick validation not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The submit button should validate all the txtboxes, so i have written this code,
but  it is not working
and **I also want that if textboxes aren't empty, then it should postback and onclick should call, otherwise not**

```
 function submit() {
      for( var i = 0, t = document.getElementsByName( "txt" ), l = t.length; i < l; i++ )     
         if( t[i].value)
            return true;

      return false;
   }
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox name="txt" runat="server" ID="email" CausesValidation="True"
                          ClientIDMode="Static"  ValidationGroup="email" ></asp:TextBox>

 <b>Password:</b><br />
                        <asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="pwd" runat="server" name="txt" TextMode="Password" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:LinkButton ID="Submit" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Login"
                             onclick="Submit_Click" OnClientClick="submit()" CausesValidation="False" />
```

Comment: Why don't you use required field validator?

Answer (score 0):

First, name is not a property in ASP.NET TextBox control, use a common CssClass property name for all the text boxes and in javascript use the document.getElementsByClassName selector to select the text boxes. Also note the addition of `return` in the OnClientClick decleration.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="test" runat="server" ID="email" CausesValidation="True"
                          ClientIDMode="Static"  ValidationGroup="email" ></asp:TextBox>

 <b>Password:</b><br />
<asp:TextBox CssClass="test" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="pwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:LinkButton ID="Submit" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Login"
                             onclick="Submit_Click" OnClientClick="return submit()" CausesValidation="False" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function submit() {
      for( var i = 0, t = document.getElementsByClassName( "test" ), l = t.length; i < l; i++ )     
         if( t[i].value=="")
            return false;

      return true;
}
```